# Assert a function result of boolean/string in PHPUnit

Tags: phpunit, assertion

I'm using PHPUnit to auto-test my app. I want to assert the result of a function call which can return a boolean or a string. My code looks like this:

```
$myExample = new MyExample();
$value = $myExample->getValue();
if ($value !== false) {
  assertNotNull($value);
  assertFalse(empty($value));
}
```

But is it also possible to check whether the method executes successfully? Is "assertTrue($value)" the correct way?

Comment: Why are you making this complicated? Assert that `is_bool($value) || is_string($value)`.

Comment: Hm, but is_bool is not an assert and that's why an unit test not "breaks"...

Comment: Yes, but `assertTrue(is_bool etc)` is.

Answer (score 9):

**UPDATE: Deprecated methods**

Please use the following ones in case you want to check the data type:

```
assertIsArray()

assertIsBool()

assertIsFloat()

assertIsInt()

assertIsNumeric()

assertIsObject()

assertIsResource()

assertIsString()

assertIsScalar()

assertIsCallable()

assertIsIterable()

assertIsNotArray()

assertIsNotBool()

assertIsNotFloat()

assertIsNotInt()

assertIsNotNumeric()

assertIsNotObject()

assertIsNotResource()

assertIsNotString()

assertIsNotScalar()

assertIsNotCallable()

assertIsNotIterable()
```

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE: As per mtiziani's comment below, this answer applies for PHPUnit versions below 9.#**

If you want to assert the data type of the value, the correct way would be:

```
$this->assertInternalType('[expected_data_type]', $value);
```

The `[expected_data_type]` PHPUnit can validate can be any of these:

```
'array'
'boolean'
'bool'
'float'
'integer'
'int'
'null'
'numeric'
'object'
'resource'
'string'
'scalar'
'callable'
```

So, to assert that the returned value is a boolean, you would:

```
$this->assertInternalType('bool', $value);
```

Comment: ```assertInternalType``` is marked as deprecated for PHPUnit 9 and has to be replaced soon, better to use ```assertTrue(isString($value))``` in future

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$this->assertSame($expect, $actual)
```

It will test for type and value (i.e. `$expected===$actual`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test if the function returns false for certain data then you might consider doing that in a separate test method.  The same with testing for a string.  If you test for one value type at a time, the asserts are less complicated.  Some people consider it to be good unit testing practice to have one assert per test method.

```
$this->assertFalse( $returnVal );
$this->assertInternalType('string', $returnValue);
```